# Trying to add a saving system but i cant get the files to change to variables on python

Tags: python

im gonna be honest i kind of have no idea what im doing so if someone could help that would be very apreciated
im trying to make a game with saving so you can save a then use load and itll read the file and restore progress but its not working

```
bag=[""]
gold=0
weapon=["cool looking stick,1"]
level=1
savefile=input("what is you name")
load=input("would you like to load a previous save")
if load == "yes":
    f = open(savefile+"'s save.bag.txt", "r")
    str(bag) == (f.read())
    f.close()
    f = open(savefile+"'s save.gold.txt", "r")
    str(gold) == (f.read())
    f.close()
    f = open(savefile+"'s save.level.txt", "r")
    level == (f.read())
    f.close()
    f = open(savefile+"'s save.weapon.txt", "r")
    str(weapon) == (f.read())
    f.close()
else:
    f = open(savefile+"'s save.bag.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(bag))
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact you're using the equality comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=` to read things, your code will fail with anything else than strings (since that's what you get from `f.read()` for a text file).

To save structured data in general, I'd recommend using JSON, but to save arbitrary classes, the [`pickle` format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is quite ideal and easier.

I've refactored things here to hold all player state in a class here:

- The `Player.load()` classmethod loads an object from a file. (It doesn't really validate that it loads a player, though. Could be any object.)
- The `Player.save()` instance method saves the object into an appropriately named file.

```
import pickle


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.bag = []
        self.gold = 0
        self.weapon = ["cool looking stick,1"]
        self.level = 1

    def save(self):
        with open(self.name + ".save", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, name):
        with open(name + ".save", "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)


name = input("what is your name?")

if input("would you like to load a previous save? [y/n]").lower().startswith("y"):
    player = Player.load(name)
else:
    player = Player(name)
    player.save()

# e.g.:
player.level += 1
player.save()
```

Comment: Thanks now i just need to watch a totourial on pickle and i should be good